# Smoothness of a real smooth normed space yields the Birkhoff orgonality is additive on the right

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, orthogonality

In a normed space $X$, the Birkhoff orthogonality is defined as following: $$x\perp_B y \quad ‎ ‎\Leftrightarrow \quad \| x+\lambda y\| \geq \| x\|.$$

A well known characterization of the Birkhoff orthogonality is: $$x\perp_B y \quad ‎ ‎\Leftrightarrow \quad \exists \varphi \in \{ \varphi\in X^* \; :\; \| \varphi\| =1, \; \varphi (x)=\| x\|\} \; : \; \varphi (y)=0.$$

A normed linear space X is called smooth if to each $x\in X$, $x\neq 0$,
there corresponds a unique Hahn-Banach functional $\varphi \in X^*$ satisfying $\| \varphi\| =1$ and $\varphi (x)=\| x\|$.

Let $X$ be a real smooth normed space. I was wondering if someone could tell me why smoothness of $X$ yields the Birkhoff orgonality is additive on the right: $x\perp_B y$ and $x\perp_B z$ implies $x\perp_B y+z$?

Thannks in advance.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Since $x\perp_B y$ and $x\perp_B z$ so there exist $\varphi_1 ,\varphi_2 \in X^*$ so that $\varphi_1 (y)=\varphi_2 (z)=0$ Is there a $\varphi \in X^*$ so that $\varphi (y+z)=0$?

Comment: If $φ(y)=φ(z)=0$ then $φ(y+z)=0$ so that $x$ is B-orthogonal to $z+y$. Am I missing something?

Comment: $φ_1=φ_2$ since $X$ is smooth

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. we have two $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Uniqueness is related to $\| \varphi \|=1$ and $\varphi (x)=\| x\|$ not related to $\varphi (x)=0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: By definition, $x$ is B-orthogonal to $y$ iff there exists $φ$ in $J_x=\{φ \in X^*...\}$ such that $φ(y)=0$. Since $X$ is smooth, $J_x$ is a singleton. So if $x$ is B-orthogonal to both $z$ and $y$ then there exists a necessarily unique $φ$ in $J_x$ that is zero at $z$ and $y$. Then $φ(z+y)=0$

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. You are right. I got it completely. Thank you very much for your help.